# CSS not functioning the same way across firefox, chrome and ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

This is pertaining the logo on my website. I wanted the monster in the logo to be seem as if sitting on the secondary menu and hence i added the following codes.

```
#logo {position:absolute; z-index:20; margin-top:-5px !important;}
#top-menu {margin-left:300px;}
```

This is the effect that i want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvSJH.png

However, although this is functioning well in chrome. it does not work well in firefox and IE. could anyone help? i tried meddling with the css on both browser, but what works in one does not carry over to the other browser.

You can browse my website at http://nomnom.sg

Comment: You need to include all the relevant code to reproduce your issue. Not just two lines of CSS.

Comment: thanks for reminding, forgot to include the site url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img#logo {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 23px 0px 0px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 13px;
    z-index: 11111;
}

ul#top-menu {
    float: left;
    padding: 25px 0px 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
```